# grub2 failed to boot Windows 8 and got blurred screen

Tags: boot, grub2, screen

Grub2 failed to boot Windows 8 and my computer got a blurred screen. Such problem happens to Windows 7 and XP too. I don't know thy only a few computers have this problem. 
 I have searched a lot online and haven't found solution.

Comment: Could you in this case please make a photo of your screen and add it to your question? But don't use the full resolution of your camera, sizes like 800x600 would be probably enough and save yours and our bandwidth (and the planet because of the lower energy need :D).

Comment: Yes I should have attach a photo of my screen, but I do not have enough Reputation to add a photo.

Comment: Just post the link of the photo in the comments without the H T T P : / /

Answer (score -1):

It´s probably a windows problem. Windows assumes that it is the only OS running on your computer (and so it is trying to load the entire hard drive but it can´t). Try to mount the windows partition into ubuntu and save your required data. After you finished that step you have to reinstall windows and declare that you wish to install it parallel to Ubuntu. After installing you need to reinstall your programs and load your data back from the hdd used for saving it.
A different (but really complicated) way of solving the problem is to mount the windows partition and fix the NTFS headers manually. But for doing such things you REALLY need to know what you´re doing. If you do so: you need to fix the partition size inside the 'registry of your windows partition' from the entire hard drive size to the new size of your partition. But note: I tried this several times and it only worked once for me.

Comment: it is trying to load the entire hard drive but it can´t: **wrong** 
you have to reinstall windows: **wrong**
fix the NTFS headers manually: *That's a really advanced feature*
fix the partition size inside the 'registry of your windows partition': **wrong**
I wish I could downvote 3 times, alas only one.
You can edit this answer to remove the factual errors or delete it altogether to recover the reputation points you just lost...